# Measure distance in distorted rectangle

Tags: matrices, geometry

We have the following rectangle. We don't know its dimensions, but we have a sample measurement inside the rectangle (the red segment):

[image]

Based on that measurement we can accurately infer the length of the blue segment. This works because this is a projection with no distortions.

Now suppose we have the same rectangle, but distorted (skewed):

[image]

We know how it's been distorted based on the 4 corners.

The question: given we have a measurement taken in the distorted image (the 10m red segment), can we accurately compute the length of another arbitrary segment (eg. the blue segment)? The only available information is the one from the second picture.

Comment: We need more information--there are lots of ways to map the rectangle to the rectangle continuously, and in general different ways will give different lengths for the blue segment.

Comment: Put another way: We _don't_ how the rectangle has been distorted based on the 4 corners alone.

Comment: We would obviously be able to measure the _"distorted"_ length of the blue line in the same way we did in the first case. But finding the original length is impossible, if we have no clue how exactly the original length changed...

Comment: What additional information would we need to unambiguously define the way it was distorted? In my scenario, all that's available are those 4 points (the rectangle is actually just a picture, taken with a camera, of a house facade). Also, if we increase the number of measured segments (the red ones), can we get a good enough approximation of the blue segment?

Comment: Also, just to be clear: in the second picture, the red segment was measured to be 10m before the distortion happened and now we simply see how a 10m segment looks in the distorted rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ABCD$ be the image of rectangle $[ABCD]$, its opposite sides meeting at vanishing points $U$ and $V$ (see figure below). I'll use $[X]$ to denote the preimage of $X$, hence $[AB]$ is a side of the rectangle, while $AB$ is the corresponding side of the tranformed quadrilateral. If $EF$ is the image of a segment $[EF]$ of known length, then we can draw the lines joining its endpoints with the vanishing points and construct segments $KL$ and $OP$ from their intersections with $AD$ and $AB$. Note that $[KL]$ and $[OP]$ are the perpendicular projections of $[EF]$ on the sides of the rectangle, hence:
$$
\tag{1}
{[EF]\over[AB]}=
\sqrt{\left({[KL]\over[AB]}\right)^2+\left({[OP]\over[AB]}\right)^2}=
\sqrt{\left({[KL]\over[AD]}\right)^2r^2+\left({[OP]\over[AB]}\right)^2},
$$
where
$$
r={[AD]\over[AB]}
$$
is the aspect ratio of the rectangle.

But we can compute $[KL]/[AD]$ and $[OP]/[AB]$ from the figure, using the invariance of [cross ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio) in projective transformations:
$$
\tag{2}
{[AD]\over[KL]}={[KA]\over[KL]}+{[KD]\over[KL]}=
(V,K;L,A)+(V,K;L,D)={VL\cdot KA\over VA\cdot KL}+
{VL\cdot KD\over VD\cdot KL},
$$
$$
\tag{3}
{[AB]\over[OP]}={[OA]\over[OP]}+{[OB]\over[OP]}=
(U,O;P,A)+(U,O;P,B)={UP\cdot OA\over UA\cdot OP}+
{UP\cdot OB\over UB\cdot OP}.
$$
Hence, if we know the aspect ratio $r$ we can compute $[AB]$ from $(1)$
and then use the analogous of formulas $(1)-(3)$ to get the length $[GH]$ of another segment.

If $r$ is not known, we might compute it [as explained here](https://andrewkay.name/blog/post/aspect-ratio-of-a-rectangle-in-perspective/) (if possible), or use another known length in the picture to get another equation to combine with $(1)$ to find $r$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help! I'll put this into practice and see how close I can get to the actual `r` based on other measured lengths.

Comment: @Razvan OK, let me know if something is not clear.